# ColdFusion: Getting NoClassDefFoundError when referencing a .NET DLL in a cfobject tag

Tags: .net, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8

I have a ColdFusion 9 instance, and a .NET DLL. The .NET DLL is very simple string parsing to make some of my tasks easier in CF. There is one DLL for each client that wants to do some client-specific tasks with the strings, but the core of pulling those items from the original source doesn't change from client to client.

In this case, I have an object that looks like:

```
public class clsNotification : BaseClass
{
    public string GetSimpleString()
    {
        return "I was here";
    }


    public string GetNotificationsXml(int ProjectID)
    {
       return MybaseClass.getXML(ProjectID);
    }
}
```

The notification class is the main DLL, and BaseClass is in a separate DLL.

**UPDATE:**
I put everything in one DLL for testing purposes, and it is still giving me the same error. The error I am receiving is:

```
coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCInvocationException: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError :
System/Xml/XmlQualifiedName][java.lang.ClassNotFoundException :
System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName]
```

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the logs folder. I guess they consider that a security risk or something. I have put the System.Xml.dll into the folder, but it still doesn't appear to be picked up by the .NET Integration Service.

Any new thoughts? Why would XmlQualifiedName be not found?

**UPDATE 2:**
The ColdFusion code is very simple. It is a cfcomponent with a function as described here:

```
<cffunction name="GetNotificationsXml" access="remote" returntype="string" output="false">
    <cfargument name="ProjectID" type="numeric" required="yes">

    <cfobject name="myObj" type=".NET" 
        assembly="#ExpandPath("./")#Published .NET DLLs/Notifications.dll" 
        class="#Namespace#.clsNotifications">

    <cfset str=myObj.GetNotificationsXml(ProjectID) />

    <cfreturn str>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace (and any errors from the `{cfroot}\jnbridge` logs)

Comment: What have you written in Cold fusion

Comment: The exception snippet is a bit ambiguous. `NoClassDefFoundError` can often mean a class is missing (or CF failed to generate the necessary proxy class) but can also indicate general initialization problems. Try adding the System.xml dll to the `assembly` list. Any change?

Answer (score 0):

I kept having this issue where a class would instantiate but an exception would result in this error.  What I figured out, through tinkering, is that even with the assembly list containing the proper dll it still fails since I presume the JNB Proxy doesn't include that class in the proxy generation.

What I do is instantiate the class directly like this:

```
<cfset nullObj=CreateObject(".net","System.Net.WebExceptionStatus"
          ,"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll")>
```

So that when/if the exception occurs there is a generated proxy for the class and the error will not occur.